# Capture an arbitrary number of values from url

Tags: django, url, django-urls

I created a url pattern in Django which captures a category in the url and passes it in the view. For example the url *mysite.com/category/shoes/* matches the path:

```
path('category/<category>/', views.Feed.as_view(), name='feed'),
```

And it will pass to the view a variable called `category` with the value `"shoes"`.

Now I want also to capture subcategories. Categories and subcategories will be organized as a tree structure, and a subcategory may have more subcategories within it. How could I write a url path pattern which captures **an arbitrary number** of nested subcategories, for example:

*mysite.com/category/shoes/winter/leather/...*

and how would this be passed to the view?

Comment: IMHO, in your case, use query parameter, not path parameter

Comment: query parameter would not be indexed as separate urls by search engines and that it matters for SEO

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Use this syntax:

```
path('category/<category>/<int:year>/<str:type>', views.Feed.as_view(), name='feed')
path('category/<category>/<str:type>/<int:size>', views.Feed.as_view(), name='feed-shoes')
```

You can alternatively use query args and add logic in your view to extract them.

```
path('category/$', views.Feed.as_view(), name='feed')
```

And in your view:

```py
if request.GET.get('category', None) == 'shoes':
    # check other params
```

Another better practice would be to split your view based on the different categories, it's bad practice to write a view that can take in an arbitrary number of arguments like that. Writing out your URLs and splitting your views would be simpler and better.

See [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: But this only captures the two variables you defined, year and type. I want to capture an arbitrary number of subcategories (the url may come with two nested categories or maybe five), and pass it to the view (maybe in an array?)

Comment: @FernandoJesusGarciaHipola you probably have to write a custom router if you want to name the url args

Comment: @FernandoJesusGarciaHipola using query args would also be easier, would you be open to that?

Comment: query args are good idea but I want categories to be indexed in different url for SEO

Comment: @FernandoJesusGarciaHipola Different categores shoud probably have different views, see my updated answer

Comment: I do not agree, there could be hundred of categories and be highly dynamic, that's why I have them in my app as a model to edit and add them easily.

Comment: @FernandoJesusGarciaHipola why don't you use the first syntax, but just add a new pattern for every custom url leading to the same view with a different path name. I haven't tested whether Django would allow that though.